# Javascript, modifying variables in other files

Tags: javascript

I have two files set up as such:

file2.js

```
var someVariable;

function setVariable(newVar){
    someVariable = newVar;
}
```

file1.js

```
const file2Mod = require('./file2');

function initializeStuff(){
    .
    .
    .
    file2Mod.setVariable(4);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

For some reason, even after I call setVariable, the value of someVariable
is still undefined. I have tried printing the value of someVariable inside
setVariable to the console before and after assignment, and it is successfully
being assigned inside setVariable. Somehow, this isn't translating when I try
to access someVariable elsewhere in file1.js. I am new to javascript, so I
am probably making a silly mistake. If more information is needed to solve the
problem, I am happy to provide. Any advice would be hugely appreciated!

Thanks!

EDIT:

I forgot to mention, I am exporting at the end of file2.js
as such:

```
exports.someVariable = someVariable
exports.setVariable = setVariable
```

Comment: Please provide an actual [mcve]. This seems like over-simplified code as you are not even exporting anything in file2.

Comment: set variable in the window context if you want this to present globally...

Comment: When you export variables, you're exporting the value of the variable at that moment. It's not going to automatically update the exported/imported value when the original variable changes.

Comment: Thank you Guy Incognito, your comment worked! Very informative, thanks so much!

Answer (score -3):

> window.someVariable = "abc"

Try this.

Comment: This is clearly Node.js. Even if it wasn't, declaring `var someVariable = "abc"` in the global scope is exactly the same as `window.someVariable = "abc"`.